# Add a curve to skew in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, distort, skew

I have an image that I have applied a skew to.

[image]

The effect that I want is that the horizontal top and bottom of the image have a curve to them.  I imagine I have to use the pen tool somehow to achieve the curve but I can't figure it out.

To re-iterate, I want to transform a rectangle image so the right side is smaller and top and bottom has an inward curve.  I need to apply this to existing image, not draw an image of that shape.

I hope I explained that correctly.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

1. Select the object outline, the screen you show above
2. Bring up the Free Transform tool (Ctrl-T}
3. You can now bring the corner handles up-down, right-left by holding the Shift key or move them freely, this will give you the trapezoid shape
4. Now, click on the icon on the toolbar that looks like windshield wiper which will make additional handles appear
5. Now, use the handle attached to a line connected to a corner and move it up or down, this will create a bezier curve effect
6. Using the same process, complete the curve effect you like
7. Press Enter to apply

See the images below as steps illustrated

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The windshield wiper like icon is greyed out, I can't select it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the Free Transform tool active? It is available only after making a selection and pressing Ctrl-T to activate the Free Transform tool. It may look grayed out, have you tried hovering your mouse over it?

Comment: Yes, I have free transform tool selected by going to edit -> free transform.  Clicking greyed out windscreen doesn't do anything. The image I am trying to edit is a group of layers. Does that make a difference?

Comment: In order to use the free transform tool you have to have either a selection or use a single layer. If you have multiple layers selected you cannot use the warp mode. You can edit each layer separately to achieve the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

@Guerrilla, you say it is a group of layers, then Photoshop wont warp it as a mesh. **Right click on group** via the *layers panel* and on the pop choose **Convert to Smart Object.**

This way the layers are fused together and the Free transform option will become active. Click on the Mesh Warping tool and adjust one of the handles/targents to Transfrom to a desired curve.

*However you can no longer edit the individual layer of the group within this Document.* You will have to right click on the Smart object and choose **Edit Contents**, Or double click on the smart object Icon in the thumb nail to open it in the new document.

Editing these contents automatically updates the parent document on saving. #Note This is a good practice as it also reduces file size and gives you more control on the individual groups.